# ArcMap: in a 10.0 Basic license and trying to edit FC coming from a 10.0 Editor edited GDB

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, editing, license

I have a feature class in a file geodatabase which is not allowing me to edit it, but is also not giving an error when I try.  I right click on the layer in ArcMap and choose to start an edit session, Arcmap starts one and if i look in the Editor menu it does show it is in an editor session, but the layer I am trying to edit shows it is NOT open for editing (ie. "Start Editing" is not greyed out).  There is no error message saying i am not licensed to edit that data.

I have had this before when working on data sets previously worked on in a higher Editor/Advanced license but I don't know what part of the puzzle keeps the dataset from being edited by lower license levels.  There is no linked Annotation or relationship class type functionality to the dataset, just a domain on it and that's it, as far as i can tell.

...I pulled the FC into a blank MXD and tried to edit and this time DID get an error dialog that i was not licensed to edit the data, so I think that IS what's happening but for some reason editing it in the other MXD does not bring up the error dialog (other MXD likely opened in the higher license previously). So what do I need to do in the higher license to make the lower licenses able to edit the dataset?

The end user is on 10.0 and not upgrading anytime soon, so I have to make this backwards-compatible as well as license-agnostic.

Comment: I just pulled the FC into a blank MXD and tried to edit and this time DID get an error dialog that i was not licensed to edit the data, so I think that's what's happening otherwise but for some reason editing it in the other MXD does not bring up the error dialog.  So what do I need to do in the higher license to make the lower licenses able to edit the dataset?

Comment: That seems to be important information for you to revise your question with using the [edit] button beneath it.

Comment: Please don't add questions or information in comments.  Edit your original question to include the info so we don't have to mine the comments.  Also, you're more likely to get help if you do so.

Comment: Perhaps there is an unresolved file lock  on it?

Comment: Please **edit** the question to specify which *kind* of geodatabase  (personal, file, or enterprise), and if enterprise, which RDBMS. ArcGIS 10.0 has been Retired for a year now, so the chance of incompatibility with more modern OSes and databases is increased.